# How to determine the exact character of a whitespace in linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to get the PID field of `ps -aux`. I know I can achieve this using `ps -aux | awk '{print $2}'`, but as practice wanted to see if I can do the same using the `cut` command. My idea is to specify a delimiter and chose the second field like this:

```
 ps -aux | cut -d[delimiter] -f2
```

Using space as a delimiter (`' '`) did not work, neither did tab (`\t`).

In general, how do I find out the exact character of a white-space in linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To identify otherwise unprintable or similar-looking characters (like whitespace), pipe output to a tool like `xxd` or `od -c`. For example, this outputs both the hex values of each character as well as the text for easy lookup:

```
ps -aux | xxd -g 1        # -g 1 outputs each character individually
```

However I think your issue is that `ps -aux` uses multiple spaces between the fields; `cut` does not handle multiple consecutive delimiters, so it prints whatever's between the first and second space, i.e. nothing.

If you really want to use cut you have to remove both leading spaces and duplicate spaces:

```
ps -aux | sed 's/^ *//;s/  */ /g' | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Answer (score 2):

cut doesn't support multi-chars as delimit. 
There are multiple whitespace between fields, if you really want to use cut:

```
ps aux | sed 's/  */ /g' | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the PID of a `ps` command you can do this:

`ps -aux | cut -c10-15`

Answer (score 1):

For information: the `u` that you use in `ps aux` means, according to `man ps`:

> u               Display user-oriented format

So you're explicitly asking for a *human readable* output and then you parse it with some tool? That's not very appropriate (to say the least). If you need to format the output of `ps`, please use the `-o` (or `--format`) option, if your version of `ps` accepts it. Hence:

```
ps ax -o pid
```

will be *much* better.

Comment: Thanks, I just figured out the `-o` flag after going through the man pages. I agree this is a much better way of doing things. On the other hand, I'm still trying to get more comfortable with linux commands so it doesn't hurt to try getting things done the harder/uglier way just to get some practice using different commands.

Comment: But it's dangerous: once you know a little bit how to use pipes, and the tools cut, awk, sed, head, tail, and all that, you'll make terrible long chains of pipes, you'll parse outputs that are not meant to be parsed, etc... (just like pretty much everybody), and it's _terrible_. I believe it's a good habit to take from the start to know how to do things efficiently and properly.

Comment: I mean, look at the other answers... nobody was worried about parsing the output of `ps`: "oh it's easy, take a little bit of cut and a salt of sed, then insert gently a awk and a grep". `:-(`.

Comment: Good point. I agree bad habits can arise from messing with pipes and chaining commands. Will try to learn the proper way. Your advice is much appreciated!